# jquery addClass function not working without throwing any error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to dynamically(on click) add "selected" class to the div element, but its neither working not throwing error. Even in the console also it just runs without working or throwing error.

```
<div class="col s8 m4 card-box cursor-pointer">
<div class="card"
     id="object__{{ key }}"
     name = "{{ value }}__{{ key }}__{{ qb_id }}"
     oncontextmenu="chapter_context_menu(event, {{ qb_id }}, {{ key }}, '{{ value }}');">
    <div class="card-content  light-blue lighten-4">
        <span class="card-title black-text">{{ value }}</span>
        <p class="grey-text text-darken-2">Chapter {{ forloop.counter }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
        {% include 'question_edition/reusable/edit_chapter/edit_chapter_icon_trigger.html' %}
        {% include 'question_deletion/reusable/delete_chapter/chapter_delete_icon_trigger.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function object_selected(card_id) {
   object_unselected();
   console.log("#"+card_id);
   var card = $('#'+card_id);
   card.addClass("object-selected");
}

$(".card").click(function(e){
    object_selected($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Console and alerts are working absolutely fine, no error. But class list remains unchanged. Please, help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: What does this do `object_unselected();`

Comment: Never mind. I resolved it.....

Comment: can you paste the html that gets generated and sent to the browser after it gets run through whatever pre-processor you are using?

Comment: @Senal, object_unselected() was a function to remove the same class from any other objects so that they are no longer selected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $('.card').on('click', function(){     /* $(_selector_).no('click',...) for work if dynamically adding divs*/
          /* for remove all selected class */
        $('.card').removeClass('selected');
        /* for add selected class on this div  */
        $(this).addClass('selected');
   });
```

```css
/* all css only for demonstration */       
       .card{
          border-style:solid;
          border-color:gray;
          border-width:4px;
          padding:2px;
          margin:1px;
          cursor:pointer;
       }
       /* add declare selected class after main class */
       .selected{
          border-color:red;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="card">card1</div>
    <div class="card">card2</div>
    <div class="card">card3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle class 'selected' on click, if clicked one more time removes it, and so on every time when click/unclick, like a switch

```
jQuery('.card').off().on('click', function card_click(){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**or**

Only add class 'selected' on click

```
jQuery('.card').off().on('click', function card_click(){
   jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

In your example

> var card = $('#'+card_id);

the wrong part is that **$('#'+card_id);** is not a DOM object. You should write like this if your DOM object has a specific card_id

> var card = jQuery("\"#" + card_id + "\"");